# How to get a specific type of key from a ssh server in C/CPP?

Tags: c++, c, ssh, ssh-keys

I would like to do something similar to `ssh-keyscan`. I've looked into `libssh` and `libssh2` but the functions that they provided only return a key that the client and the host agreed on.
I also checked out `ssh-keyscan` source code but it seems really complicated with all the global flags being set left and right.

So my question is, is there any easy way through some kind of library to implement this kind of functionality or do I have to take the `ssh-keyscan` like approach and set up almost everything manually?

Answer (score 1):

Imo, `ssh-keyscan` connects once for every key type it supports, trying to agree on that key. If that succeeds, it prints the key, if not, it proceeds with another.

---

What makes the code complicated is that it does all the connections *in paralel in a single thread*. If you implement it sequentially, it will be way more simpler.